# Make Skype for Business less horrible-looking?

Tags: skype, user-interface

At my new job, we use Skype for Business (SfB). As a chat client, it works sort of okay (although there are things such as the chat history* that are too simplistic or harder to get to than they should be). But my main grief is with the UI.

Apparently, a modern GUI app needs to consist of large panels of mostly white space (exhibit A: [Skype for Business](http://www.lyncinsider.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/skype4Bfiletrans.png)), even on non-touch-displays.

[image]

In the "old days", things were much more compact ([exhibit B: Sametime](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/sametime75/figure1.jpg)).

[image]

It irks me that two simple chat windows must lay claim to half a (largish!) monitor. Is this *really* necessary? **Is there an alternative?** Perhaps an older version of SfB that retains a more *sane* user interface? Or better yet, would it be possible to use some version of Lync, Sametime, Trillian, Pidgin, or similar without sacrificing (too much) functionality or making it too obvious to my peers at work? It absolutely needs to work as a client up against a Skype

I ask because I have almost no experience with "post-XP" Windows and other MS software, and I'm mostly flabbergasted by the direction MS is taking their general UI style. The first thing I do on any post-XP machine I get is to revert the OS theme to that "classic" one (sadly, apps such as Office and Chrome don't respect this). Mind you, I'm not trying to incite a flame war, just trying to find a solution.

* In Sametime, when you send/receive a message to/from a person you've communicated with earlier, the chat history is [right there](http://www.adamgartenberg.com/gartenberg/agartenberg.nsf/dx/sametime-quick-tip-automatically-save-chat-transcripts.htm/content/M3?OpenElement). In Skype, this requires much more digging around, and even then isn't always complete. Any way to make the chat "continuous" would be highly appreciated (I realize this might warrant a separate question).

Comment: Your ability to use an older version of Lync would depend on your office.  Lync is a license product, Skype for Business is a license product. It all depends on your infrastructure your job is using  Go ask somebody at your job that knows the answers to these questions, we don't, and your asking us so you apparently don't either.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that licensing is not a problem; we're using Office 365 and 2013 everywhere. What I'm after is not "what am I allowed to do" within the company, but rather "what might actually work" from a technical point of view. So I'm asking here to get in touch with a wider population possibly familiar with a range of chat clients.

Comment: Office 365 means you are using cloud based licenses for your Lync needs.  Lync was rebranded as Skype for Business.  What might actually work is entirely depends on your office and what their infrastructure is like.  I can tell you third-party clients are not going to unlikely to work on a cloud based infrastructure for Lync/Skype for Business.  I am not aware of any third-party client that can be used with a Lync/SFB backend.  It a matter of third-party client support for the proticol more then anything.